# Opinions on Solr and spatial data structures for very large datasets

Tags: c++, database, spatial

Ok so I'll try to keep this simple.  The technical aspects of the problem are, no problem...

I'm looking for some opinions on Solr database indexer.  I have 25 million approx items that need to be stored in some kind of spatial structure.  These are all GIS records with coordinates stored as lat/lon.  One of my co-workers has been using Solr for this task but I'm looking to do some performance tests against several spatial tree types.  We're currently using mySQL for storing all of our data, Solr for indexing and I'm investigating Postgres with PostGIS.  I'm assuming Solr is using some kind of multi-dimensional B-Tree, but I could be wrong and am looking for confirmation on this.

I'm also going to be running tests on this dataset using...
- B-Tree
- B-Tree (with Morton Hash Index)
- B-Tree (with Hilbert Hash Index)
- BSP-Tree
- Quad-Tree
- KD-Tree
- R-Tree

I'm going to be writing either an Apache module or MySQL/PostgreSQL extension in C++ for each of these tests, and following implementation once we make our decision.

I'm just looking for opinions/suggestions on said implementation.

Thanks